# netbens al intentar poner una foto como icono en un boton el codigo esta bien el error es al ejecutar

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

El error esta al ejecutar el programa el codigo esta bien ya que si quito las imagenes el programa me corre perfectamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]b.png[image: mi proyecto es POEP3A2]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

línea 53 de la clase ESTACIONAMIENTOVIP

```
btnsalir.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/IMAGENES/SALIR.png")));
```

Comment: sin código no podemos ayudarte, te recomiendo compartirnos por lo menos la línea 53 de la clase `ESTACIONAMIENTOVIP` y realizar el *build* antes de correr tu aplicación

Comment: Te doxeaste solo bro :C

Comment: Cómo? No entiendo